# Append Base Template to Template using Sitecore Powershell

Tags: powershell, xpath, sitecore

I'm new to Sitecore PowerShell (and PowerShell in general), and I would like to generate a script that adds a Template as a Base Template to a list of ChildItem Templates under a certain context folder.

Since __Base template is a standard value and not a regular Field, I'm not sure if there is a syntax available to append a GUID to the multilist field that it uses (pipe delimited).

**Here's what I've tried**

```
$master = Get-Database master;
$translationTemplate = $master.Templates["Path/To/Template/Needed/Translatable"];
$calloutTemplate = $master.Templates["Path/To/Example/Callout"];

#$translationTemplate;

$calloutTemplate += $translationTemplate;
```

I'm able to get all of the children recursively with Get-ChildItem -recursive, but for a test run, I just want to try it on one Template Item called Callout. Here's a view of the $calloutTemplate, showing that it has a BaseTemplates section and a Fields section (which should include __Base template):

[image]

If there is no solution in Powershell for Sitecore, would Sitecore Rocks Query analyser CRUD operations possibly work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically the script you're looking for is:

```
$templateToExtend = Get-Item 'master:/templates/Path/To/Example/Callout'
$templateToAdd= Get-Item 'master:/templates/Path/To/Template/Needed/Translatable'

# Make sure we're not adding it again if it's already there
if(-not ($templateToExtend."__Base template" -match "$($templateToAdd.Id)"))
{
    "Adding '$($templateToAdd.Name)' to '$($templateToExtend.Name)' Base templates"
    $templateToExtend."__Base template" = "$($templateToExtend.'__Base template')|$($templateToAdd.Id)" 
}

# Just to verify it got added:
$templateToExtend."__Base template"
```

However just that doesn't really give PowerShell justice. The power of it is that you can now turn this snippet into a function that can be piped into. You can do this easily following [Michael's tutorial on his blog](http://michaellwest.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/SPE-CreatingFunctions.html)

Comment: Getting used to this syntax will definitely be worth diving into PowerShell for Sitecore. It's like the equivalent to using Perl scripting for heavy IT admin tasks. Thanks for the code snippet. Do you  happen to know of any references for Sitecore related update operations to items and fields (I'm starting to realize that Fields in Sitecore can be accessed a lot easier than I thought)?

Comment: You mean in Powershell? All of the fields are exposed in their storage form. You can address any field by just using the $item.FieldName or if it has a space $_."Field Name" and then assigned to. I think only dates are different as I expose those as DateTime object.
  
  The benefit to this over Perl or Bash is that you're actually working with the live Sitecore API rather than text.